# Jquery: Show only topmost image in image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build basic imager slider using HTML , CSS and Jquery.
while moving left(750px), it's moving only top most image and not showing remaining images.

it seems like it's moving all images in one shot instead only top most image.

HTML file:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demolayout.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
</style>

</head>
<body >

<div class="container">
<div id="slider">
<ul class="slides" >
        <li class="slide"><img src="5.jpg" alt="Chania"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="5.jpg" alt="Chania"></li>
        <li class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg" alt="Chania"></a></li>
        <li class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg" alt="Chania"></a></li>
        <li class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg" alt="Chania"></a></li>
        <li class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg" alt="Chania"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>


</body>
```

.CSS file:

```
  #slider {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
    }

#slider .slides{ 

  width:6000px;
  height:400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;

}

#slider1 .slide{
  float: left;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:240px;
  height:400px;
}
```

.JS file:

```
$("#slider .slides").animate({'margin-left':'-=650px'},1000)
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/q3c21f7q/1/

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: added jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add jQuery in your JSFiddle.

I've add a function that could display your slides with an interval time.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3c21f7q/7/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    var nextItem = $(".slide.active").fadeOut().removeClass('active').next('.slide');

    if (nextItem.length === 0) {
        nextItem = $('.slide').first();
    }

    nextItem.addClass('active ').fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. but my concern is why all images are moving left instead of only one. I can find multiplay ways to create image slider in google but i am more interested on what has gone wrong with my code.

Comment: It's because your selector is too large to only pick the first one. You can change it by this one : `$("#slider .slides li:first-child")` to pick the first one only.
See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q3c21f7q/8/

Answer (score 0):

In your js file, your code will move the slider 750px to the left only once, when the code is loaded. The slider is the container of the slides, so it will obviously move all your slides...

Not sure how you plan to create a working slider out of this code, but here are some tips:

- set your list as a horizontal one with:

  ```
  li.slide { display: inline; }
  ```
- Then, use `setInterval` to move your slider to the left each 2 secs. for example:

  ```
  setInterval(rotate, 2000);

  function rotate() {
    $("#slider .slides").animate({
      'margin-left': '-=750px'
    }, 1000);
  }
  ```

But you still have to find a way to come back to the first position when all the pictures have been shown.

---

To create a slider, I would suggest a slightly different approach:

- first, hide all the slides (here, your `ul`).
- have a special `div`, empty at first, which will show one slide at a time
- every X seconds :

  1. if the `div` already contains a slide, cut it and paste it at the end of your `ul` (easy with jquery)
  2. take the first `slide` of your `ul` and insert it in your `div`

Another way to go is to use an `.active` class, like the one @VincentG suggests.